# Facebook page post likecount not showing on website like button

Tags: wordpress, facebook-like

Recently my **facebook post** likes are not showing up on my website like button.

For instance my article http://motorivista.com/honda-cb750f/ is showing only **8 likes**.

But on my facebook page this article post have **28 likes**.

http://www.facebook.com/MotoRivista

Likes I received on the links I post on Facebook have always combined with likes received from the actual article on my website up until a few days ago. Now the Facebook ones are not adding to the count on my website. Can anyone help please? Thanks

Regards,

Jake

Answer (score 1):

I think **28** is the number of **likes for the wall post** which contains the link to your actual article. **8** is the number of **likes for the actual article** ( user clicked when he/she was reading your actual article).